# How to prevent Sprite Nodes from pushing each other?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground, skphysicsbody

3 Sprite Nodes are moving up at different speed levels. You see that the gorilla likes to rest, but the lobster is pushing it slowly upwards. Expected behaviour would be, that the lobster would rest also and continue going upwards when the gorilla starts moving again. Using .isDynamic = false did not work — the Sprite Nodes were overlaying and lobster ignored the physical body of the hedgehog and the gorilla totally.

Recording of my Playground Scene: https://youtu.be/l47kaJiJvkM

Screenshot of the video: 
[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
import SpriteKit

public class WalkingScene: SKScene {

public override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = .white

    view.showsPhysics = true

    let hedgehog = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hedgehog")
    hedgehog.size = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)
    hedgehog.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: 400)
    hedgehog.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))
    hedgehog.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    hedgehog.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false


    let gorilla = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gorilla")
    gorilla.size = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)
    gorilla.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: 140)
    gorilla.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))
    gorilla.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    gorilla.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false


    let lobster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lobster")
    lobster.size = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)
    lobster.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: 20)
    lobster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))
    lobster.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    lobster.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false


    //        hedgehog.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    //        gorilla.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    //                lobster.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    //        hedgehog.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    //                hedgehog.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    //        gorilla.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    //                gorilla.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    //        lobster.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    //                lobster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    self.addChild(lobster)
    self.addChild(hedgehog)
    self.addChild(gorilla)

    self.moveGorilla(gorilla)
    self.moveLobster(lobster)
    self.moveHedgeHog(hedgehog)
}

func moveGorilla(_ passenger: SKSpriteNode) {

    let moveLeft = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 200)
    let aYYY = CGVector(dx: 200, dy: 0)
    let moving = SKAction.move(by: moveLeft, duration: 1)
    let turnAYY = SKAction.move(by: aYYY, duration: 1)
    let chill = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)

    passenger.run(SKAction.sequence([moving, chill, moving, chill, turnAYY])) {
        print("Gorilla arrived")
    }
}

func moveLobster(_ passenger: SKSpriteNode) {

    let moveLeft = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 200)
    let moving = SKAction.move(by: moveLeft, duration: 1.2)

    passenger.run(SKAction.sequence([moving, moving, moving, moving, moving, moving, moving, moving, moving])) {
        print("Lobster arrived")
    }
}

func moveHedgeHog(_ passenger: SKSpriteNode) {
    let moveLeft = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 200)
    let moving = SKAction.move(by: moveLeft, duration: 1)
    let chill = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)

    passenger.run(SKAction.sequence([chill, moving, moving, moving])) {
        print("Hedgehog arrived")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are they set as kinematic?  I am confused by the `isDynamic` setting as physics bodies can be one of three types: static, dynamic or kinematic.

Comment: Its SpriteKit, not SceneKit

Comment: SpriteKit doesn't have kinematic physics bodies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set those dynamics this way:

```
     hedgehog.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
     gorilla.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
     lobster.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```

By this strategy, you can extend this example to other situations.

If `isDynamic = true` is treated as 0 , and the `isDynamic = false`, ie `static`,  treated as infinity, 
there is something between which can be controlled by the mass of a physics body.

```
    hedgehog.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false. (mass = Infinity)
    gorilla.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true. (mass = big)
    lobster.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true  (mass = 0)

    gorilla.physicsBody?.mass = 1000
```

Comment: But then, gorilla is pushing the hedgehog. If I set them false/false/true, the hedgehog and gorilla are overlapping. If I set them false/false/false, the lobster is ignoring all (as described above)

Comment: Okay, thank you it worked! The question is, why does it not work if every node is set to .isDynamic = false? Does it not work because a node with infinite mass can push another node with invite mass?

Comment: Yes, if dynamic is true , because three objects has the same default mass, 1.0  and the simulator just randomize the priority which can lead to some unwanted behavior. If dynamic is false, simulator will ignore the physical behaviors and may produce other unexpected results.

Comment: So if I want to add another node to the queue, the mass should be lower than of the previous node?

Comment: Yes. It’s decreasing from top to bottom. Maybe it has some 10 folder between each.

Comment: Thank you very much